# Java composition constructor

Tags: java, constructor, composition

I create some kind of a basic rpg. I use composition (Character and Fighter) and there's a problem in CharacterCreator class. It says that there're incompatible types, Game.Fighter (and rest of the character classes I created) and Game.Character. Any idea why and how to fix this?

```
public class Game {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Character hero = CharacterCreator.createCharacter();

    try {
        hero.displayCharacter();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Wrong");
    }


}

}

public class CharacterCreator {

public static Character createCharacter() {
    System.out.println("Choose a character: ");
    System.out.println("1. Fighter");
    System.out.println("2. Rogue");
    System.out.println("3. Mage");
    System.out.println("4. Cleric");


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int scan = sc.nextInt();
    String chosenClass = getCharacterClass(scan);

    System.out.println("Choose Name:");
    Scanner nameIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = nameIn.next();

    Character hero = null;

    switch (chosenClass){
        case "Fighter":
            hero = new Fighter(name);
            break;
        case "Rogue":
            hero = new Rogue(name);
            break;
        case "Mage":
            hero = new Mage(name);
            break;
        case "Cleric":
            new Cleric(name);
            break;
        case "def":
            System.out.println("Wrong input");
    }

    return hero;
}


public static String getCharacterClass(int scan){

    String classIn;

    switch (scan) {
        case 1:
            classIn = "Fighter";
            break;
        case 2:
            classIn = "Rogue";
            break;
        case 3:
            classIn = "Mage";
            break;
        case 4:
            classIn = "Cleric";
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Enter again");
            classIn = "def";
    }

    return classIn;
}

}

public class Character {

private String name;
private String characterClass;
private int level;
private int hp;
private int currentHp;
private int armorClass;

private long xp;
/*private int BAB; /*Base attack bonus*/

private int strength;
private int constitution;
private int dexterity;
private int intelligence;
private int wisdom;
private int charisma;


protected Character(String name){

    setName(name);
    setCharacterClass("Class");
    setLevel(1);
    setStrength(10);
    setConstitution(10);
    setDexterity(10);
    setIntelligence(10);
    setWisdom(10);
    setCharisma(10);
    setHp(0);
    setCurrentHp(getHp());
    setArmorClass(10);
    setXp(0);

}


void displayCharacter() throws IOException {
    System.out.print("\n\n\n");
    System.out.println("Name: " + getName());
    System.out.println("Class: " + getCharacterClass());
    System.out.println("Level: " + getLevel());
    System.out.println("HP: " + getHp());
    System.out.println("Current HP: " + getCurrentHp());
    System.out.println("Armor Class: " + getArmorClass());

    System.out.println("***************");
    System.out.println("Attributes: ");
    System.out.println("Strength: " + getStrength());
    System.out.println("Constitution: " + getConstitution());
    System.out.println("Dexterity: " + getDexterity());
    System.out.println("Intelligence: " + getIntelligence());
    System.out.println("Wisdom: " + getWisdom());
    System.out.println("Charisma: " + getCharisma());
    System.out.println("***************");
    System.out.println("XP: " + getXp());

}

public int getModifier(int number){
    int mod = (int)((number -10)/2);
    return mod;
}

public String getName() { return name; }
public String getCharacterClass() { return characterClass; }
public int getLevel() { return level; }
public int getHp() { return  hp; }
public int getCurrentHp() { return  currentHp; }
public int getArmorClass() { return  armorClass; }
public int getStrength(){ return strength; }
public int getConstitution(){ return constitution; }
public int getDexterity(){ return dexterity; }
public int getIntelligence(){ return intelligence; }
public int getWisdom(){ return wisdom; }
public int getCharisma(){ return charisma;}
public long getXp(){ return xp;}


protected void setName(String Name) { name = Name; }
protected void setCharacterClass(String characterClass) { this.characterClass = characterClass; }
protected void setLevel(int lvl){ level = lvl; }
protected void setHp(int hitPoints){ hp = hitPoints; }
protected void setCurrentHp(int curHp){ currentHp = curHp; }
protected void setArmorClass(int ac){ armorClass = ac; }
protected void setStrength(int str){ strength = str; }
protected void setConstitution(int con){ constitution = con; }
protected void setDexterity( int dex) { dexterity = dex; }
protected void setIntelligence(int intel){ intelligence = intel; }
protected void setWisdom(int wis){ wisdom = wis; }
protected void setCharisma(int cha){charisma = cha; }
protected void setXp(int XP){xp = XP; }

}


public class Fighter  {

    Fighter(String name){

        Character hero = new Character(name);

        hero.setName(name);
        hero.setCharacterClass("Fighter");
        hero.setLevel(1);
        hero.setStrength(14);
        hero.setConstitution(16);
        hero.setDexterity(14);
        hero.setIntelligence(10);
        hero.setWisdom(10);
        hero.setCharisma(10);
        hero.setHp((int) (10 + hero.getModifier(hero.getConstitution())));
        hero.setHp(10);
        System.out.println("hero.getconst(): " + hero.getConstitution());
        System.out.println("hero.getModifier(getConstitution(): " + hero.getModifier(hero.getConstitution()));
        hero.setCurrentHp(hero.getHp());
        hero.setArmorClass(10 + hero.getModifier(hero.getDexterity()));


}


}
```

Comment: You're not posting the exact and complete error message, which is the most important piece of information. What you should also do ASAP is rename Character to something else: it conflicts with java.lang.Character, which will cause you endless pain.

Comment: java: incompatible types: Game.Fighter cannot be converted to Game.Character

Comment: And the faulty line of code is?

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33321850/edit) your question (Clic my link or the "edit" link right above) and post as JBNizet said the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The class Figter is declared as

```
public class Fighter {
```

So it does **not** extend from the Character class. So a Fighter **is not** a Character.

Yet the `CharacterCreator` class has the following method:

```
public static Character createCharacter() {
    // ...
    switch (chosenClass){
        case "Fighter":
            hero = new Fighter(name);
            break;
            // ...
    }

    return hero;
}
```

So you're trying to return a Fighter from a method which must return a Character. And a Fighter is not a Character. Hence the error message.

Comment: I get your point. It should be a composition, not inheritance. Then how can I solve it ?

Comment: Composition consists in having a "has a" association between two classes. So I guess you want Charater to have a field of type Fighter, and to have a constructor such as new Character(someFighter). But given the names, that doesn't seem right at all. I don't even understand why you have a Fighter class: it doesn't have any field, nor any method. All it has is a constructor that creates a Character. It's useless.

Comment: I want to get a character class (like fighter) as an input and create a character according to the chosen character class (like fighter), with  predetermined stats/abilities. A charcter has a character class rather than a character class is a character, of course. As you said, the constructor should look like Character("Fighter). Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get a character class (like fighter) as an input and create a character according to the chosen character class (like fighter), with predetermined stats/abilities.

Create a static fighter creator method in Character (to have access to the protected setXxxx() methods), create a new Character instance, and override the desired statistics.

```
class Character {
    public static Character createFighter(String name) {
        Character hero = new Character(name);
        hero.setStrength(14);
        hero.setCharacterClass("Fighter");
        hero.setStrength(14);
        hero.setConstitution(16);
        hero.setDexterity(14);
        hero.setHp((int) (10 + hero.getModifier(hero.getConstitution())));
        hero.setCurrentHp(hero.getHp());
        hero.setArmorClass(10 + hero.getModifier(hero.getDexterity()));

        return hero;
    }
}
```

Alternately, pass the character class into the Character constructor:

```
class Character {
    public Character(String name, String charClass) {
        // Initialize defaults
        setStrength(10);
        setIntelligence(10);
        // etc

        switch(charClass) {
        case "Fighter":
           setStrength(14);
           // ... other overrides for Fighter
           break;
        case "Cleric":
           // etc
        }
    }
}
```

However, if you are going to be doing many checks against the character class, you should use an enumeration.  And then you could even put initial stats inside the enumeration class.   See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html especially the Planet example.